# Does the surrounding of an object detection model matter in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

My question is, when I label images of X object. Do I also need to label images of X object with different types of background? (Outside the box area)?

How does the object detection model work? Does the background of labelled images have any impact?